# Required Field Missing/Variable does not exist

Tags: apex, unit-test

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, 値を入力してください: [Company]: [Company]

Getting the above error when running the test class. However, when i try to enter company into the designated area (code below), it tells me the variable does not exist.

```
 Lead leds = new Lead(lastname='Test', email='1@2.com', company='Test');
    insert leds;

    user u = [select ID from User where ID ='00536000008S5wA'];


System.runAs(u) {
    //Insert our first task
    Task t = new Task(subject='Test Activity', whoId = leds.id);
    insert t;

    Lead l = new Lead() ;
    l.LastName ='Test';

    // .. Add other fields 
    l.Number_of_Activities__c  =1 ;
    insert l ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The field `Company` is mandatory for the `Lead` object unless you have Person Accounts activated. On your test code, set `l.Company` to a test value and your code should work.

For Example, add to your test code the following line

```
l.company = ‘Test’;
```

PS: you should never hardcode a Id in your code, try creating your own user instead. That way your code will continue to work even if the designated user is deactivated or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You used a Hardcoded Id so that is not in the best practices in Salesforce. And you have missed mandatory fields Company and a status field. please try the below code:

@isTest
public class TestClass 
{

```
  @isTest
 public static void test(){
    Lead leds = new Lead(lastname='Test', email='1@2.com', company='Test',Status='Working-Contacted');
    insert leds;
    // u1=UserInfo.getUserID();
    //user u = [select ID from User where ID ='00536000008S5wA'];
     System.runAs(new user(ID = UserInfo.getUserID())){

        //Insert our first task
        Task t = new Task(subject='Test Activity', whoId = leds.id);
        insert t;

        Lead l = new Lead() ;
        l.LastName ='Test';
        l.Company='Ca';
        l.Status='Working-Contacted';    
        // Add other fields 
        l.Number_of_Activities__c  =1 ;
        insert l ; 
    }



}
```

}

Please select it as Best answer if you find it helpful.

Thank You,

Ajay Dubedi